# SharePoint 2013 How to update a lookup column in different lists?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column

SharePoint 2013 updating a lookup column from another list not working

Lists:

1. IP Range: Includes a title column (single line of text) for ip ranges (ex. 10.1.1.x)
2. IP List: Includes columns for ip range (lookup to IP Range List), ip address (single line of text) and status (lookup IP Status List)
3. IP Status: Includes Title column (single line of text) with two entries, allocated and unallocated
4. System List: Includes IP Range (lookup), IP Address (Lookup)

Creating a new item in System List and selecting a range from IP Range loads the "Unallocated" ip address in IP Address Column but doesn't change IP Status List column from "Unallocated" to "Allocated."

How can I make "Unallocated" change to "Allocated" and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Per your description, you need to change the status for the selected IP address in IP list. Why do you want to change status in IP Status list?

You can create a Designer workflow for System List. Using the workflow, find the status field based on the IP address and update the status to “Allocated” in IP List when an item is created in System List.

If you also want to change “Allocated” to “Unallocated” when an IP address is not selected, you need to [create an Event Receiver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-an-event-receiver) to handle list item events in System List. For example: [ItemUpdating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [ItemDeleting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemdeleting.aspx)…

A list of [SPItemEventReceiver methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver_methods.aspx)

Using the Event Receiver, when an item is updating/deleting, get previous value of Status before updating/deleting and update Status in IP address List.

Comment: I want to change the status (allocated or unallocated) in IP List not IP Status List.  I misspoke.  I will setup a workflow in SPD and let you know how it goes.

Comment: How are things going?

Comment: I'm still working through this.  Trying to find the right conditions and actions.

Comment: In the workflow, you can use "Update List Item" action.